# Power off and reboot buttons

Tags: shutdown, interface

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and I have just installed it. Problem is that power off and reboot buttons don't work. I'm turn off my PC by long push off POWER button on my laptop. How fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To shutdown type the following command:

```
sudo poweroff
```

or:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

to reboot type:

```
sudo reboot
```

2) Edit `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`

Open terminal and type:

```
nano /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
```

It will be something like:

```
# /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
# This is called when the user presses the power button and calls
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh for further processing.

# Optionally you can specify the placeholder %e. It will pass
# through the whole kernel event message to the program you've
# specified.

# We need to react on "button power.*" and "button/power.*" because
# of kernel changes.

event=button[ /]power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

To save type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
To exit type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Edit `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` and add the following lines:

```
# If all else failed, just initiate a plain shutdown.
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

Save , exit and type:

```
sudo service acpid restart
```

Comment: In addition, if you want to type a command, you can either go to tty by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`-`F6` and login, or start a terminal emulator on your desktop by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`.